# System logs out on video playing in Full Screen

Tags: 11.04, video, fullscreen, logout

After upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04, a strange behaviour i am getting on video playing full screen in Totem, vlc, smplayer, xine player. The system logs out every time i play a video, almost all video formats i have tried.

I have resolved this problem, changing video drivers of the said player to x11,

1. smplayer: Options --> Preferances--> Video --> Output Driver --> x11(slow)
2. vlc: Tools --> Preferences --> Video --> UNCHECKED Accelerated Video Output

Now the Videos are playing on FULL-SCREEN without logging off.

As of totem movie player, couldn't find this option, how to change.

However, this seems odd, that i have not noticed this thing in previous versions of Ubuntu i have used.

Here, i want to know **how to change/configure the video driver option in Totem Movie Player...?**

Comment: It is unclear what problem you need our help for (see also [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask)). Your observation may be a graphic card driver bug.

Comment: check your .xsession_errors in your home dir and log files in Log File viewer for errors related to playing video.

Comment: It happened to me as well (but doesn't happen anymore).

Comment: It seems that you've fixed the problem, I don't mean to sound rude, but why did you post this?

Comment: [http://askubuntu.com/users/18395/synicade] thanks for pointing out, i postedhttp://askubuntu.com/users/18395/synicade this question here, to know option for configuring the video driver in Totem movie player. Now i have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: However, this post has helped at least one person, i am Happy with that. Possibly i get my answer too, now.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a way to configure Totem movie player but you can disable the default output
that is causing the problem as a workaround by doing the following.

1. Right click "Applications) on the top panel.
2. Select "Edit Menus"
3. Select "Preferences" under the Menu section on the left side.
4. Select "Multimedia Systems Selector" on the right side.
5. Click close.
6. On the panel, click "System", "Preferences" and then "Multimedia Systems Selector".
7. Click the "Video" tab.
8. From the "Plugin" dropdown, select "X Window System (No XV)"
9. Click close.
10. Logoff and then login.
11. Enjoy Fullscreen video in Totem and Firefox. :-)